# Principle of induction in ZF

Tags: set-theory

I'm going through Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory* and he's just defined the natural numbers and proved that it is an inductive set. Then he says the following:

> Induction principle for $\mathbf{w}$: Any inductive subset of $\mathbf{w}$ coincides with $\mathbf{w}$.

I'm a little confused here. Is this an axiom? Is this a theorem? If it is, how would it be proven?

Comment: It's a theorem, and you prove it in the same way you prove any set equality: supposing $A\subseteq\omega$ is inductive, you need to prove $\forall x[x\in A\leftrightarrow x\in\omega]$. Of course, the nontrivial bit is proving the right-to-left direction ...

Comment: The idea I have of a proof would use the successor function infinitely many times, which I wouldn't say is valid at this point of the book. What can I do?

Comment: How is $\omega$ defined for you?

Comment: The set whose members are exactly the natural numbers, which is proved to exist by the axiom of infinity and the axiom of specification.

Comment: And your definition of natural number is ... ?

Comment: A set that belongs to any inductive set.

Comment: OK, so suppose $A$ is an inductive subset of $\omega$ and $x\in\omega$. Since $x\in\omega$, what do we know about $x$ and inductive sets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137209/discussion-between-darsen-and-noah-schweber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, with Noah Schweber's help, it was an easy consequence of the definition of natural number:

If $A\subseteq\mathbf{w}$ is an inductive set, and $x\in\mathbf{w}$ then $x$, being a natural number, is an element of every inductive set, so $x\in A$. Consequently, $A=\mathbf{w}$.